# ElasticSearch span near query not producing expected results with nested span queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an odd scenario. I have a document which contains the text "6 Music Live Hour".
The second part of the query - span_term matching "Hour" produces no results when written as below

```
  {
    "span_near" : {
      "clauses" : [
        {
          "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
              {
                "span_term" : {
                  "all_field" : {
                    "value" : "6",
                    "boost" : 1.0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi" : {
                  "match" : {
                    "wildcard" : {
                      "all_field" : {
                        "wildcard" : "M*c",
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop" : 0,
            "in_order" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "span_term" : {
            "all_field" : {
              "value" : "Hour",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop" : 2147483647,
      "in_order" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
```

However, when I change this to a wildcard query it produces the expected result. See below.

```
  {
    "span_near" : {
      "clauses" : [
        {
          "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
              {
                "span_term" : {
                  "all_field" : {
                    "value" : "6",
                    "boost" : 1.0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi" : {
                  "match" : {
                    "wildcard" : {
                      "all_field" : {
                        "wildcard" : "M*c",
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop" : 0,
            "in_order" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "span_multi" : {
            "match" : {
              "wildcard" : {
                "all_field" : {
                  "wildcard" : "Hour",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop" : 2147483647,
      "in_order" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
```

Please can anyone advise on what I'm doing incorrectly in the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the text to lowercase and then building the term query produced the expected results.